# Whitney $C^\infty$ topology for Riemannian Metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm currently reading the paper "Quadrants of Riemannian Metrics" by Fegan and Millman (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029002001).

In the proof of Proposition 5 at the bottom of page 4, they say "Let ... $W(K,U)$ be a basic open set of the Riemannian metrics on $M$ (so that $K\subset M$ is compact and $U\subset S^2M$ is open)." I assume this $W(K,U)$ has to do with the Whitney $C^\infty$-topology on $C^\infty(M,S^2M)$, but this notation is not defined in the paper, nor in any of the references, as far as I could tell. I also couldn't find anything about this notation on the Wikipedia page for Whitney topologies, nor in my Differential Geometry textbooks.

If anyone could help elucidate this for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A standard neighborhood of the weak $k$-Whitney topology consists of all functions $f$ such that $\partial^k f (K) \subset U$ for a compact $K$ in the domain of $f$ and an open $U$ in the range of the $k$'th derivatives of $f$. More details in Hirsch's _Differential Topology_ (1976).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Thanks for the reference, it's been helpful.